# How to Read .csv File From Browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So what I'm trying to accomplish is quite simple, I'm trying to read a local .csv file so that I may use the data in my vue web application. I found that the sheetjs library can do exactly that, and also has utilities that will come in handy. However, upon trying to access and read the file, I get a "cannot access file" error. Upon research, I found this information: "Browsers have no API for reading arbitrary files given a path, so another strategy must be used". However, I need to accomplish this from the browser for my current vue project. Any tips?

Comment: The browser can read a file that the user gives it access to by way of [loading it into an `<input type="file" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).  Would this meet your requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not looking to receive a file, rather, I'm using my own spreadsheet file to display data. I'm looking to do this in the frontend/browser, if possible.

Comment: This is possible only through @Alexader Nied comment or an AJAX request.

Comment: You don't need to upload the file to the server-- once the user has dragged it to the file input the browser can access its contents.

Comment: @itsmygit The AJAX approach actually sounds like a possible solution...I can upload my spreadsheet onto, let's say,  a document library/sharepoint, and then from my application frontend I can AJAX to that document and get the data back that way. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: Well it depends, but because of CORS restrictions that is one of the possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
In the html do:`<input id="fileId" type="file" />` and in the javascript:

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('fileId').files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) { 
const contents = e.target.result;
console.log(contents);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```